# Over write plugin templates

Tags: plugins, functions, hooks, woocommerce-offtopic

Is that possible for overwriting a plugin templates via making a folder in theme file and copy the file in that folder and altering the content [both folder and file name have the same name as arranged in plugin ].

Generally we altering the woocommerce page templates by following these system .Is that possible for all plugin ?

If no , what code that make woocommerce plugin to change the style based on the file inside our theme folders woocoomerce folder ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not possible with all plugins. This is a feature the developer has to provide on their own.

Usually how it works is the plugin will look for the template file in the child theme first. If it's not found there, it looks for the template in the parent theme. Finally, if it's not found in either of those places, it uses the template included with the plugin.